# Itearator in Array Deque Data Structure in Java

Tags: java, arraydeque

```
static ArrayDeque<Integer> bfs = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
static Iterator<Integer> revbfs = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();

revbfs=bfs.descendingIterator();
```

very quick question. I want to return the bfs in reverse order. There is the descendingIteartor method, I'm just not sure what it's returning. What would revbfs be in this case? How am I to use the method to get to my reverse order?

Comment: What is preventing you from writing piece of code to explore/test behavior of that iterator on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is very easy to test with this code:

```
public class Test {
    static Deque<Integer> bfs = new ArrayDeque<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bfs.add(1);
        bfs.add(2);
        bfs.add(3);

        Iterator<Integer> revbfs = bfs.descendingIterator();
        while(revbfs.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(revbfs.next());
        }
        // output is 3, 2, 1
    }

}
```

Also, the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html#descendingIterator()) can be very helpful, in this case:

> Iterator descendingIterator()
>
> Returns an iterator over the elements in this deque in reverse
>   sequential order. The elements will be returned in order from last
>   (tail) to first (head).

Try searching, reading and testing whenever you are unsure of certain class/method behavior.